# ElasticSearch JVM Heap goes over 75% and nodes are dead

Tags: java, elasticsearch, jvm, heap-memory

I am running a elasticsearch cluster with 3 nodes. Each node has an heap size of 12g - ES_HEAP_SIZE=12g .

I am uploading the stats from Marvel so you can see the moment where the nodes are dead in the moment where the JVM Heap is over 75%.

[image]

After I restart the nodes everything runs fine again. Until the next peak. On every peak on the graph the nodes are not responding anymore.

Some ideas?

Edit: my JVM Heap usage for the last hour
[image]

Is the graph looking fine?

Comment: How much memory do your nodes have? Generally you want to use ~50% of the available memory for Elasticsearch, and ~50% for Lucene